# Pull Up Resistor to Substitute SPDT Function

Tags: resistors, switches, flipflop, pullup

I'm creating a circuit to switch and control between two different analog signals, and I'm doing so with JFETs and a CD4013. If I'm using a guitar pedal stomp switch to pull up or down the data line, can I use a pull-up resistor in this configuration to mimic an SPDT switch?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGovoA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your design using a pullup resistor should work fine. It will draw a little more current from the battery when the button is pressed, but it's less than a milliampere and should be negligible.

Sometimes you have to worry about switch contact "bounce" but since your switch data goes through a flip-flop that latches the switch signal, this should not be an issue. Good luck!

Comment: Ah yes, flip-flop kills/cures bouncing.